# dot notation with dynamic property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have the following class that I use for a core data storage.

```
@interface CVMessage : NSManagedObject {
    NSString * message;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * date_created;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * message;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * mid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CVLogin * creator;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet * stars;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet * embeds;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CVTopic * topic;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL options;

@end

@implementation CVMessage
@synthesize options;
@dynamic message;
@dynamic mid;
@dynamic creator;
@dynamic date_created;
@dynamic embeds;
@dynamic stars;
@dynamic topic;
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

CVMessage * mes = [CVMessage new]; 
 mes.message = @"some text";

my intuition is that I'd have to implement my own setter for this, so I have:

```
-(void)setMessage:(NSString *) newMessage
{
    if (self.message != newMessage)
    {
        [self.message release];
        [newMessage retain];
        self.message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error when I run it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.message = newMessage` is the same as `[self setMessage:newMessage]`, so you are probably getting infinite recursion there, and the error is probably an stack overflow.

Just access the variable directly:

```
-(void)setMessage:(NSString *) newMessage
{
    if (self.message != newMessage)
    {
        [message release];
        message = [newMessage retain];
    }
}
```

Comment: I was gonna say the same. One more thing: I think normally you should copy NSString properties instead of retaining.

Comment: I tried that at first, but I got the error:


Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'CVMessage' 
-[CVMessage message]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdb405a0
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CVMessage message]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdb405a0'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: As far as generated code is concerned, **there is no difference between the two method expressions Emilio**.

Comment: `self.message =` uses `setMessage:` indeed, but you can either do `message =` or `self->message =` to access the ivar directly.

Comment: anyone care to comment on the error I got for implementing the above?

Comment: @Adit: did you implement the getter? `-(NSString *)message`

Comment: turns out the way I initialize CVMessage is causing this,=